# PHPStorm shows the directory but no files

Tags: php, phpstorm, vendor

Hello I've installed socketo.me a few days ago, everything worked unbelievably. But for some reason now, the vendor folder has nothing in it (In PHPStorm), but If I look at it outside of phpstorm, like with windows file view, it shows all of the files and folders within the Vendor folder.

I am not sure whats happening here, I've tried restarting phpstorm, and replacing folder, no luck.

Live preview of what happens:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/05cbf2afb278ab9f5f04d4a681566a54.gif))</sub>

What is wrong?

Another thing, the IDE actually can see the listing files, as when I try to open a project and browser, i see them:

[image: img2]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/c7838cb1defeaadc2ce54d36572c582f.png))</sub>

Comment: Try right clicking the project folder and hitting the synchronize button.

Comment: @Axel No luck, but if i open another project with Socketto installed, it will show dirs, + i copy pasted the directory from that project.

Comment: Maybe File | Invalidate caches and restart will be helpful?

Comment: @Kootli Just tried, same problem

Comment: @user3123545  try to start IDE with the defaults by renaming setting folder (.WebIde70) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108 . Also: any third-party plugins? Any exceptions in log (Help | Show log)? What is the JDK version?

Comment: Latest JDK version (1.7.0_55) iirc updaetd it week ago using winodws java updater.

Comment: 1) Your system Java version does not matter as IDE comes with their own copy of Java (on Windows), unless you have manually configured IDE to use your copy of Java. 2) You are using v6 .. while v8 is about to be released in a month or two. Consider upgrading -- it has few improvements when working with file system (you can try EAP build right now -- can be run in parallel to v6 -- http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm )